# Magento2 Get Customer Group ID in topmenu.phtml

Tags: magento2.3, navigation, customer-group

I am needing to show a totally different navigation bar links if a customer is logged in as a wholesaler customer group.

I am using Magento2.3 and a child theme of Luma. What I did was edit the topmenu.phtml as seen below to get the customer group id and then if the customer group id is a specific # to show a static block My issue is no matter what I clear cache etc it still just shows the customer id as 0 regardless if I am logged in or not. Yet the same code works in the footer.phtml and other files just not in the topmenu.phtml file?

```
<?php
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

   if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) 
   {
       $customerGroupId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
   }
   else
   {
        $customerGroupId = 0;
   }

   $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0;
   $_menuHtml = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit)

?>

 <nav class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
     <?php
        //if user is a wholesaler
        if($customerGroupId == 2) 
        {

          echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('wholesale-top-nav-bar')->toHtml();

        }
        else
        {
      ?>
        <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
          <?= /* @noEscape */ $_menuHtml?>
          <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
        </ul>
    <?php
         }
    ?>  
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that your `phtml` name in the layout  is `catalog.topnav`

I suggest that you have to use `Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` class to get customer group id to get customer group id at your template file.

Create `default.xml` at your module and add a class [a view model](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html) and pass customer group from view model to phtml file.

### View Model Class:

```
<?php

namespace {Vendorname}\{Modulename}\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;


class CustomerGroupInfo implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    private $httpContext;

    public function __construct(Context $httpContext)
    {
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }
    public function getCustomerGroupId()
    {
        return $this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_GROUP);
    }
}
```

Add this view model to layout for customer group id in your **phtml** file from **default.xml**.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <page  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
>     <body>
>     <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
>         <arguments>
>             <argument name="customer_view_model" xsi:type="object">{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\ViewModel\CustomerGroupInfo</argument>
>         </arguments>
>     </referenceBlock>
>     </body>
> </page>
> ```

Then on `phtml` on access  by `getCustomerGroupId` below code:

```
<?php

/** @var $viewModel \{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\ViewModel\CustomerGroupInfo */

$viewCustomerModel = $block->getCustomerViewModel();

$viewCustomerModel->getCustomerGroupId();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use session factory. Using session is a singleton. If I was to do it in the code you presented

```
<?php
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory')->create();

   if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) 
   {
       $customerGroupId = $customerSession->getCustomerData()->getGroupId();
   }
   else
   {
        $customerGroupId = 0;
   }

   $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0;
   $_menuHtml = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit)

?>

 <nav class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
     <?php
        //if user is a wholesaler
        if($customerGroupId == 2) 
        {

          echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('wholesale-top-nav-bar')->toHtml();

        }
        else
        {
      ?>
        <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
          <?= /* @noEscape */ $_menuHtml?>
          <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
        </ul>
    <?php
         }
    ?>  
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you user3685048 but that does not seem to work still?